# What tool can I use to easily manage data within a cloud database (Azure/SimpleDB/etc)?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, web-applications, azure-sql-database, amazon-simpledb

I need a cloud database as a back-end for a mobile app, most of them will do what I need, but I also need a management interface (ideally web-based, but could be a Windows client) that makes it easy to:

1. Add/edit data in the database (including cross-table forms)
2. Report on the database, ideally with dashboards/charts

So I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a web-based too that can be hooked up to one of the main cloud-database providers, that allows me to design forms and reports to manage the data in the database. My goal is to avoid writing all the forms and reports myself so I can focus efforts on the client mobile app.

Right now my "best" solution appears to be Microsoft Access (probably hooked up to Microsoft SQL Azure), and I cannot believe I'd have to sink that low. Save me from this depravity? Please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Engine datastore has built in datastore viewers (and editors). On the dev_appserver, this is accessible at `/_ah/admin/datastore`, and in production it's accessible through your app's admin console. Neither one lets you build forms and reports, though - reports are somewhat out of scope for most NoSQL databases.

If you're prepared to do some coding, you might want to consider Django, which makes constructing admin interfaces extremely straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using SDBNavigator. It's a Chrome browser plugin. Works like a charm.
 ["SDB Navigator on the Chrome web store"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg?hl=en-US&hc=search&hcp=main)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SimpleDB, check out [sdbtool](http://code.google.com/p/sdbtool/).  It's a Firefox plugin.  Very simple app - never had a problem with it.

Comment: sadly sdbtool cannot keep up with Firefox's ridiculous new version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDB Explorer. SDB Explorer is world leading GUI to explore Amazon SimpleDB. It have many features like --

1. Upload My Sql data to amazon simpledb.
2. Supports interface for AWS IAM.
3. Export Domain.
4. Product support.
5. See more .. http://www.sdbexplorer.com/